# Document database to store html content

Tags: php, mongodb, hbase, document-database, nosql

I have been working on a project where user can create simple templates and develop his website pages.He can save them and also put it over the internet once completed.Now my problem

1. When the user is working on his template he can save his copy of work done and come back to it later(Similar to drafting an email).
2. This saved work by the user is saved in **xml** files currently by parsing the template pages.
3. I was thinking of an alternative over this to store the entire page itself in a document database against a unique user id,so that there is no need of any parsing to be done and reduce the load and time.

**Now my questions**

1. Is what I am thinking possible using a **Document Database**  or nosql instead of xml?
2. If yes which one would be more **flexible** to work on and easy to maintain?
3. I am using php and mysql for other operations,so I need the doc DB just to store the html of the templates created by the user.

Comment: any reason to not use an existing CMS ?

Comment: The ultimate goal is to design a system where user can create a full fledged website,something similar to WIX,the idea is under construction,but the current scenario is what I described.A CMS would be more front end then storing templates I guess.If you say something like Wordpress,then its not upto that level currently,but can't say about future. ;) :P

Comment: Yes, one of the many NoSQL DBs will work well for you.  Also, I would keep the whole thing in that database, unless you have a specific reason you need a traditional DB.  I was working on a CMS once, but never finished it.  Basically, I had structured documents (various fields could be filled out, title, description, body HTML, etc.).  Then for displaying these documents, that was all done with PHP.  PHP would query Mongo, render the document, and you're done.

Comment: @Brad I need just a little bit clarification on how the html document would be saved.I mean the entire html page itself or we need to do some parsing to get the tags out of it.The current approach we follow is to save in xml bcoz it allows to create custom tags.So we parse the document get the tags and save it as xml document.**Please add it as an answer so that I can accept and close the thread**.Thank you

Comment: Your question isn't really going to get you much insight: yes, you can store this content in any database format.  SQL or NoSQL isn't relevant given the details provided, since it sounds like you are just saving chunks of HTML templates.  A document database may be better suited if you want to structure your content for more flexible querying at the field level.  In SQL you can use a `TEXT` field to store  large chunks of HTML (for example, MySQL's `MEDIUMTEXT` is up to 16Mb, which is the same as the current maximum document size in MongoDB).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've written a custom CMS before. I created a table structure that allows me to store both metadata (author, publishing date, language e.t.c) and content (separately) because I also wanted to implement a search feature that would allow me to search them separately. I did mine in MySql, but I had to do a lot of html-encoding to prevent attacks possible in SQL, so for that reason, I'd recommend a NoSQL database (Mongo / Cassandra should be sufficient).

I've never really worked with Mongo before. You could also use Cassandra. I prefer it because it can be schema-less (well like many NoSQL data stores). So, you can store thousands (if necessary) of revisions in one row so that your user can be able to rollback to a previous version of the page if they need to. You would then clear all the backup data once they feel that they are satisfied with the current revision. This is just a suggestion. Check out http://cassandra.apache.org or http://www.datastax.com/technologies/cassandra

Hope it helps :-)

Comment: So,is it possible for me to store the user templates that user stores directly in the document database?I mean no need to perform any parsing or encoding,but just fetch the entire page content and dump it into database.When the user comes back to edit,display the same page stored and he can start from where he left.

Comment: YES: On the server side, you can store your document directly as it is. I would recommend using `html_entities` still just to insure safety though. Also be aware that any type of storage (including the one you currently use) won't (according to my experience) prevent Cross Site attacks as these are performed on the client side, but I suppose this question was only aimed at addressing the storage concern. But that is also a subject to pay close attention to if you plan to allow people to render HTML into your site.